# Why isn't the copy assingnment operator called when the copy construcotr is not available in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, constructor-overloading, copy-assignment

Why when let's say I have an object declared like this: `Obj o1;` which is initialized by the default constructor (not very important here, how was `o1` initialized, the point is it was initialized) and I create another object in this manner: `Obj o2 = o1;` the copy constructor is implicitly called, but if I delete the copy constructor, then, I get a compile error. Why the object `o1` is not assigned/copied to `o2`, like here: `Obj o1; Obj o2; o2 = o1;`? Why the compiler tries to call a constructor in any instance? Is the `=` operator within `Obj o2 = o1;` overloaded?

Comment: *The equals sign, =, in copy-initialization of a named variable is not related to the assignment operator. Assignment operator overloads have no effect on copy-initialization.* [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)

Comment: Assignment operator assumes the left side already exists.

Comment: Copy-initialization might *elide* calling the copy-constructor, but the copy-constructor must still be available (i.e. not deleted) for it to be possible to copy the object.

Comment: Many symbols in C++ mean diffferent things in different contexts. `=` is one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, this

```
Obj o2 = o1;
```

has nothing to do with assignment. It is a little unfortunate, often confusing, use of `=` for initialization when otherwise `=` means assignment.

Also mentioned in comments, the `operator=` has to assume that the left operator already exists. Consider this somewhat contrived example:

```
#include <vector>

struct my_vect {
    my_vect() : data(2) {}
    my_vect(const my_vect& other) : data(other.data) {}
    my_vect& operator=(my_vect& other) {
        // this has already been constructed,
        // hence data.size() is 2 already
        data[0] = other.data[0];
        data[1] = other.data[1];
        return *this;
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> data;
};
```

It is a structure that contains a `std::vector` whose size is always `2`. The vector is initialized upon constructing a `my_vect`. When assigning one `my_vect` to another, then `data` needs not be initialized. Only the values must be copied. Because `operator=` assumes that the left hand side operator is already properly constructed (it merely copies to `data[0]` and `data[1]`) it cannot possibly be used to construct an object (in the example, accessing `data[0]` or `data[1]` would be out of bounds).

TL;DR: Constructors construct objects. Assignment assigns to an already existing object. Thats two fundamentally different things.

Comment: Yes, but here I have ``Obj o1 = o2;``, and ``Obj o1;`` is enough for initializing the object, as long as the default constructor is called, thus I expected ``Obj o1 = o2;`` to be executed as ``Obj o1; o1 = o2;`` as long as no copy constructor is provided.

Comment: But for this two instructions had to be executed, separately.

Comment: @pauk this could be happen, but thats just not how C++ works. In general default construction plus subsequent assignment is more expensive than only copy construction, hence it is good that in C++ you have to explicitly ask for it when you want it. I mean nothing prevents you from writing `Obj o1; o1 = o2;` when that is what you want